# Override Vuetify Icon component

Tags: css, vuejs2, components, overriding, vuetify.js

I have created a component which wraps the default  component to make it behave better with font-awesome.

Since font-awesome icons are not square it leads to inconsistent sizing and alignment issues. I resolved this by creating a wrapper which forces the element to be square and by using "font-size: 100%;" it ensure the irregularly shaped icon is contained.

Problem is that all of the vuetify components which have the "prepend-icon" / "append-icon" still appears badly when using font-awesome.

I would like to know if there is a way to import v-icon under a different name, use it in my wrapper component then define my wrapper as the rightful v-icon. Which in theory would resolve the alignment/sizing of all the vuetify components using prepend/append icon.

Does anyone have any knowledge how I could override a library component like this?

Thanks

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a very similar thing, where I had to replace the default icons (in an older version of Vuetify) with SVG ones throughout the project while still wanting to use the `v-icon` component.

I ended up creating a [custom icon component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#custom-components), called let's say, `SVGIcon.vue`. Then I defined some icon names like so:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  icons: {
    // reusable custom icon
    'vuejs': {
      component: FontAwesomeIcon,
      props: {
        icon: ['fab', 'vuejs']
      }
    }
  }
})
```

*(Example taken from the Vuetify documentation.)*

You could also pass customized 'props' to each icon that you define.

Finally, you can use it like this:

`<v-icon>$vuetify.icons.vuejs</v-icon>` (*vuejs* being the name of the icon.)

This is what I ended up doing at least. For you, this might be too long-winded. In any case, do let me know what you think of this approach.